# Функции вызывают друг друга с++

Tags: c++, функции, область-видимости

Я совсем поверхностно знаю с++, но эту проблему мне необходимо срочно решить(нет времени на прочтение книги).

Две функции remover и found рекурсивно вызывают друг друга. Но т.к remover объявлена выше, то она не видит found. Если их поменять местами, аналогично found не будет видеть remover. Понятно, что это происходит из-за того, что одна объявлена раньше другой. Тогда как решить эту проблему?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int remover(int *arr, int size, int a, int b) {
int secondArr[size];
for(int i = a; i < size-b; i++) {
    secondArr[i] = arr[i];
}
size = size - a - b;
return found(secondArr, size, a, b);

}

int found(int *arr, int size, int a, int b) {
if ( size > (a+b) ) {
    return remover(arr,size,a,b) + remover(arr,size,b,a);
} else {
    return 1;   
};
};

int main()
{
  // Входные данные
  int size = 5;
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int arr[size];

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // Заполнение массива
      arr[i] = i+1;
    }


   found(arr,size,a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявить одну из функций предварительно

```
int found(int *arr, int size, int a, int b);

int remover(int *arr, int size, int a, int b) {
  ...
  return found(secondArr, size, a, b);
}

int found(int *arr, int size, int a, int b) {
  ...
  return remover(arr,size,a,b) + remover(arr,size,b,a);
}
```

P.S. `int arr[size];`, `int secondArr[size];` для неконстантного `size` - такого в С++ не разрешается.

Comment: А что тогда делать с size, если у меня по очереди создаются разные массивы с разной длиной?

Comment: @Borod Использовать `std::vector`, например.